# iphone add view controller as subview

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog

I would like to show a modal view but don't want to use the standard methods because they don't let me animate the subview as I like.
I *tried* the fowlloing code:

```
EventsCalendarController *calController = [[EventsCalendarController alloc] init];
calController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self presentModalViewController:calController animated:YES];

[calController release];
```

but the problem is that I would like to show it using some animation, so I am using the following code along with [UIView beginAnimation] etc...

```
EventsCalendarController *calController = [[EventsCalendarController alloc] init];
calController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self.view addSubview:calController.view];


[calController release];
```

The problem is that whenever I call the following code from the 'EventsCalendarController' I get an exception:

```
- (IBAction)btnClose_TouchUpInside:(id)sender {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

here is the exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType btnClose_TouchUpInside:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7029d60'
```

How can I solve/overcome this problem? Thank you.

**UPDATE**:
Solved: I found the following code on GitHub: https://github.com/horaceho/iphone-custom-dialogbox
It is a complete example with very few code to write. I did not find the original author, so I am just linking to the code...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to remove the calendar view which you have added as a subview ? if so then
the code must be like this :

```
[calController removeFromSuperview];
```